# Python 3.12: Correct typing for list[list[int,str,list[list[str]]]]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I have a list of users, that I would like to type correctly, but I'm not able to find an answer explaining how to do this.

The list looks like this:

```
listofusers = [[167, 'john', 'John Fresno', [[538, 'Privileged'], [529, 'User']]]]
```

I tried doing like this:

```
def test(listofusers: list[list[str,list[list[str]]]]) -> None:
    ...
```

But VS Code only shows typing for: `list[list[str]]`:

[image: screenshot]

I also tried using Union, like this:

```
listofusers: list[list[Union[int,str,list[list[str]]]]]
```

But again, this doesn't seems to work.

Can someone shed a light over this?

Comment: I would recommend to implement a user class which encapsulates the information, e.g. using a dataclass. If you also need validation, take a look at https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/

Comment: @CarlosHorn Looks promising, thanks for sharing that! Please provide an answer with that, it's amazing.

Comment: I gave you an idea. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77920223/2648551) answer, having such complicated structures look like code smell. You can think of re-organising your code a bit and do some more explicit semantics:

```py
import dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Data:
    data_id: int
    attribute: str


@dataclasses.dataclass
class User:
    user_id: int
    name: str
    fullname: str
    data: list[Data]


user_1 = User(
    user_id=167,
    name="john",
    fullname="John Fresno",
    data=[
        Data(data_id=538, attribute='Privileged'),
        Data(data_id=529, attribute='User')
    ]
)
```

The code above is just an example (maybe I missed somewhere a detail, but I hope you get my point). The details are fully up to you. The advantage is that your `listofusers` becomes simply: `users: list[User] = [user_1]` with better readability, no?

You can also use [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/), of course. It is very similar to [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) (using it behind the scenes AFAIK) and has some convenient simplifications regarding data verification.

Answer (score 4):

List types can't be specified on a per-position basis: the recommended thing to have with lists under typing, and also, common sense, is for lists to be homogeneous: they should contain a single element type. If one needs to group data with different semantics (even if they would be of the same type) in  a sequence, a `tuple` should be preferred.

So, if you really can't, or are unwilling to, create a class for each element in your outer list, which would correctly encapsulate the information, with fields and such, this data:

```
listofusers = [(167, 'john', 'John Fresno', [(538, 'Privileged'), (529, 'User')],)]
```

Could be typed as:

```
list[tuple[int, str, str, list[tuple[int, str]]]]
```

But this is really "double plus ungood" if you are worried with a large system for long term maintainability.

You should obviously have a User model with four fields, the fourth being a sequence of a Permission model.

Comment: Again, thank you so much for taking the time to write this answer. I've chosen the other answer primarily because it fits my situation a lot better and we have tons of classes and functions that need better typing.